# Regular Expressions - Insert Multiple Times

Tags: php, regex

Same for example I have this:

```
Hello world!!
Hello all!
```

I want replace each "!" with a period for example.  With PHP.  How would I do that?

Comment: Do you want to replace multiple exclamation marks with a single period, or do you want to replace them with the same number of periods?

Comment: With the same number of periods.

Answer (score 5):

Don't you think str_replace would suffice?

```
$str = str_replace('!','.',$str);
```

Comment: No I need to do regex for other operations.

Comment: I still don't see a reason to use regex, given your "With the same number of periods" comment. Note that str_replace can handle more than one character

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace('#\!+#s', 'what_ever_you_want', $subject)
```

Comment: Sorry about question but why you used this # and s symbols?

Comment: The first character of a PCRE regexp is the delimiter, in this case the pound sign. After the ending delimiter may be placed a number of modifiers which change how the expression functions. In this case, the `s` modifier is being used.

Comment: # is delimiter, you can use what ever you want as a delimiter (except regex metacharacters i think, but im not sure) and "s" is a modifier which makes it multi-line compatible.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out out.  I cannot believe I didn't see this before.  ! is a metacharacter so I need a '\' before it.  That's why it wasn't working.  Thanks.

Comment: `!` is not a metacharacter. `preg_replace('/!/', '.', 'Hello world!!');` => `Hello world..`